# How can I know in Excel VBA what thousands separator to use in number formats?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel

How can I know from a VBA code if a number can be accepted with `.` or`,`?

When using format function like `format(num, "##0,000)` I get an error if the regional setting for the decimal point is "."

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
Sub dural()
    MsgBox Application.International(xlDecimalSeparator)
End Sub
```

for the decimal separator and:

```
Sub dural2()
    MsgBox Application.International(xlThousandsSeparator)
End Sub
```

for the thousands separator.

Comment: And more https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840213.aspx